# How to convert this method from using java.io.File to java.nio.file?

Tags: java, spring, image, spring-boot, file

Basically I have this method that I got off a tutorial (My main goal is to simply return the images from the spring boot server so that I could dynamically view them in Angular)

```
@RestController
public class FileController {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/allImages")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getImages(){
        List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
        String filesPath = context.getRealPath("/images");
        File fileFolder = new File(filesPath);
        if(fileFolder!=null) {
            for(final File file : fileFolder.listFiles()) {
                if(!file.isDirectory()) {
                    String encodeBase64 = null;
                    try {
                        String extention = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName());
                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                        encodeBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
                        images.add("data:image/"+extention+";base64,"+encodeBase64);
                        fileInputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

With the current code, when I try to return the files, I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because the return value of "java.io.File.listFiles()" is null
```

I've been searching around and noticed that people recommend using `java.nio.file` instead but I'm a little lost on how would I implement this here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to verify that ```filesPath``` points to the directory you expect by f.x. logging it.

Comment: Verified it, the path leads correctly to the image folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with this code:

```
@Autowired
    ServletContext context;
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/allImages")
    public List<String> readImages() throws IOException {
        return Files.list(Paths.get(context.getRealPath("/images")))
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(this::encode)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
      }
    
    private String encode(Path file) {
        try {
          String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getFileName().toString());
          String encodeBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Files.readAllBytes(file));
          return "data:image/"+extension+";base64,"+encodeBase64;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return null;
        }
      }
```

Thank you to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

First get a `Path` to your folder:

```
Path folderPath = Paths.get(filesPath);
```

If your `Path` points to a directory, you can get a `Stream<Path>` of its contents using `Files.list`:

```
if (Files.isDirectory(folderPath)) {
    List<Path> files = Files.list(folderPath)
         .filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Do something with the files.
}
```

It doesn't look like you are using the `FileInputStream` for anything, so you shouldn't need to translate that part. To get the file extension of your path, you probably need to convert the `Path` to a string, and extract the extension yourself.

Comment: So folderPath has the correct path to the images. However, for some reason, even though I have nio imported, isDirectory() is not resolved.

Comment: @Mantas Sorry, it should have been `Files.isDirectory(path)`. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Example with nio:

```
  public List<String> readImages() throws IOException {
    return Files.list(Path.of("/images"))
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .map(this::encode)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private String encode(Path file) {
    try {
      String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getFileName().toString());
      String encodeBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Files.readAllBytes(file));
      return "data:image/"+extension+";base64,"+encodeBase64;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I get `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \images` after the method runs.